# Why this is showing not a function - javascript

Tags: javascript, function, tostring, indexof

I have a statement

```
var data = "Lorem Ipsum";
```

And i'm doing

```
console.log(data.indexOf(data));
```

Which is showing

```
Uncaught TypeError: data.indexOf is not a function
```

Basically i want to get the `indexOf` the `data`

I cannot change the output

`console.log(data.indexOf(data1))`.

Instead i can change the statement. `data.toString()` will not work, since data is already in string.

How to achieve this?

Comment: In this line, console.log(data.indexOf(data1)).  What is data1 ?

Comment: *data.toString() will not work* Why? Have you tried `typeof data`?

Comment: what are u trying to achieve?

Comment: @JayabalajiJ thats a typo

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong, because I get `0` in my console on jsfiddle.net

Comment: working for me https://jsfiddle.net/c02q564x/

Comment: What do you want to achieve by the statement data.indexOf(data)? If you try to find the same string in itself, you will always get 0.

Comment: Are you resetting `data` to a boolean or something? Maybe you missed that somewhere? If I set `data = true` then I get `Uncaught TypeError: data.indexOf is not a function`

Comment: The way this is written `data.indexOf(data)` if it is a string as prior line it will always be 0 so just hard code 0 instead...

Comment: If [`String.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) is not a function, it's time to update your ancient browser ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this is working on chrome console and giving 0
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe error of common js confliction try to find confliction of this 
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">`

```js
var data = "Lorem Ipsum";
console.log(data.indexOf(data));
```

Comment: why importing jquery for this??

Comment: yea it's working without jquery too. but sometimes it may be not i have updated answer.